# Emberjs app initialize fail when creating ArrayController

Tags: ember.js

When I try to initialize my ember App with an ArrayController I got an issue but only when ember-data is added to the project. Here's a quick example at http://jsfiddle.net/ySmZr/2/

```
App = Em.Application.create();
App.customerController = Em.ArrayController.create({});
App.initialize();​
```

return the following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined  (ember-data-latest.js:3693)
```

Without ember-data I got no error. I looked everywhere and I just can't find why ember is acting like this... Any idead ? Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling initialize() you must set Router stuff. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ySmZr/5/)

**From documentation:**

> You can provide a subclass of Ember.Router as the `Router` property of
>   your application. An instance   of this Router class will be
>   instantiated and route detection will be enabled when the
>   application's   `initialize` method is called. The Router instance
>   will be available as the `router` property   of the application

There are 2 solutions:

- call initialize(), provide Application with router and use its
  capabilities
- don't use initialize()

Comment: What about the ArrayController ? If i add one I got the same error :

http://jsfiddle.net/ySmZr/6/

Comment: It's possibly a bug. If you instead extend controller it's not reproduced. See http://jsfiddle.net/ySmZr/7/. In last discussions Ember.JS developers say we don't need to create controllers ourselves. Read about it at https://gist.github.com/2728699

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ember Data, you have to create a class of the controller (capitalized) and then extend the method. So it should look like:

App.CustomerController = Em.ArrayController.extend({});

Then, you just call an instance of the controller whenever you need to use it.